# Javascript Ajax call not working?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to make POST request using Ajax call but i am getting error with status code 0 , where as all the request parameters are working in Advanced REST Client.

**MyCode:**

```
<button>Post</button>

$('button').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
        url: "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
        type: "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json',
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer 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',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
              "personalizations": [{
                "to": [{
                  "email": "test@example.com"
                }]
              }],
              "from": {
                "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
              },
              "subject": "Great, World!",
              "content": [{
                "type": "text/plain",
                "value": "Cool OK!"
              }]
            }),
        dataType: "json",           
        success: function (response) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(response)
            alert(resp.status);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error : "+status+" :: "+JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
 });
```

This is my above code , while running it's keep on throwing error saying

`{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

Also check in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Deeptiman/dt529fpp/4/)

Please help me out , suggest me some solution , i am not able to find the problem in the code.

Comment: It is throwing `405 Method Not Allowed` Please check the parameters which you are sending and relevant method in service layer

Comment: yes 405 but the same request parameters are working fine in Advance Rest Client..

Comment: I recommend to use Fiddler to see how the request looks like when it is send via the Advance Rest Client and how it looks like when you are sending it using the above code. I think it is about CORS. When you are trying to post to different domain, the browser sends the prefly reqest using OPTIONS verb, and for that request you are getting the response NOT ALLOWED (because the server does not support this http verb) and that is why the POST does not work.

Comment: I think the best way to solve this is to implement your own handler (hosted on your own site) and send the data to sendgrid using that handler.

Comment: @xxxmatko Thanks , can i enable in CORS in the code itself... because in current scenario changing the site to my host may be a longer task for me , please help me out

Comment: The CORS must be enabled on the server side, take a look at this page which handles all CORS settings "all over the world" http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: What language you use on the server side in your application?

Comment: Javascript and i have hosted in Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser extensions aren't as limited to Cross Origin Requests as the browser itself. So an extension like Advance Rest Client or Postman are allowed to request Cross Origin Resources.
See this article from Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

So when you create a website that wants to access resources from another domain, you have to enable CORS, just as Matt was saying.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a CORS issue maybe?

If you're interested in learning about cors.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html
This says nothing about being ajax accessible, so it might not be possible to do this with a direct ajax request.